# How to create VertexRDD from vertex input files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx

I have a vertex input file like this:

```
(1L,(0.5,0.5))
(2L,(0.25,0.0625))
(3L,(0.125,0.125))
(4L,(0.0625,0.0625))
(5L,(0.0625,0.25))
```

which I'm going to convert into a `RDD[(Long, Array[Double])]`.

I know this method works:

```
val Vertices=sc.makeRDD(Array((1L,Array(0.5,0.5)),(2L,Array(0.25,0.0625)),(3L,Array(0.125,0.125)),(4L,Array(0.0625,0.0625)),(5L,Array(0.0625,0.25))))
```

but the problem is I'm going to get that data from text file.

I have already tried using:

```
val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, Array[Double])] = sc.textFile("ads/tes").map { line =>
  val row = line.split("[\\r\\n]+")
  (row(0).toLong, Array(row(1).toDouble,row(2).toDouble))
}
```

but I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` error which makes me confused. Can anyone help me? Appreciate any effort thanks!

Comment: Can you please share a sample data of the file that you are using as input?

Comment: its at the top of the question
(1L,(0.5,0.5))
(2L,(0.25,0.0625))
(3L,(0.125,0.125))
(4L,(0.0625,0.0625))
(5L,(0.0625,0.25))

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But depending on how it is on your data source will depend if the split is correct or not. I think there could be the issue.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean with "how it is on your data source" that is the whole data, and the data is like that. it stored locally

Comment: Which is the character that you have in the plain text that is used to separate your values? (comma, tabs, etc) Based on that your split should use it as well. Another thing is, when you use `.textFile` you are going to take each row in your file, so in your `.split` you don't need `\\n`.  Basically, `NumberFormatException` could be raised because the array of strings from `.split` could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to split each line into the three numbers. Using `map` you will treat each line in the RDD separatly, however, in your current code you try to split on `"[\\r\\n]+"` (newlines) which is incorrect.

Instead, first remove all unnecessary characters, then split on `,`. The code will then be:

```
val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, Array[Double])] = sc.textFile("ads/tes").map { line =>
  val row = line.replaceAll(["\\(\\)L"], "").split(",")
  (row(0).toLong, Array(row(1).toDouble, row(2).toDouble))
}
```